# Embedded Mono in C++ Starting C# ServiceBase

Tags: c#, c++, service, mono

Is it possible to use a C++ application that has a mono runtime embedded inside of it to perform a mono_jit_exec on a C# app that is a service (uses ServiceBase to start)?

I can start a simple C# application from a C++ app that has a normal C# application (not a service) but I'm having some trouble starting a service.

Is there a difference?

Thanks,

mj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A service would make sense as a separate process, so you would basically execute:
system ("mono-service2 yourprogram.exe") or use fork/exec etc.

Comment: Okay, so are you suggesting that it's not possible to have a C++ app w/ embedded Mono which starts a C# service?

Comment: No, I'm suggesting that what makes sense to do usually is to run it as a separate process. Invoking a Service can be done, in fact any mono application is a C app that embeds mono and runs managed code. Maybe you're not doing the correct things to run a service, see the mono-service sources for the way to do it. Or you can detail what you're doing and what specific problems you get and we'll be able to pinpoint what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Okay, I've dug into this further. 

I think that the way mono-service can start services is that under the covers, it calls mono which turns around and calls a C# assembly called mono-service.exe passing in some arguments (in the mono-service.in script in the source code this appears). 
I'll keep digging.